# Disable entirely QuoteCharacter in DelimitedLineTokenizer

Tags: spring-batch

My problem is exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734632/unterminated-double-quotes-in-spring-batch) question but I can not use the solution mentioned.

A sum-up:
A csv file is read but contains double quotes like this `Everything is ok&"some text& this must be another field"&`...(& is delimiter)
So by this example, the parsing is wrong as it assignes multiple fields to one
The answer on the above question won't help due to the wide variety of text in the csv(No safe quoteCharacter).
I also tried to disable quoteCharacter by putting this piece of code inside xml configuration:

```
<bean id="lineTokenizer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
        <property name="delimiter" value="&" />
        <property name="quoteCharacter" value="" />
            ...
```

But got a nice exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customLineMapper' defined in class path resource [migration-job.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lineTokenizer' while setting bean property 'lineTokenizer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lineTokenizer' defined in class path resource [migration-job.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'char' for property 'quoteCharacter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String [] with length 0 cannot be converted to char type
```

Is it possible to read double quotes without assigning the quoteCharacter constant, or something else that might fix this problem?

UPDATE:
tried also this:

```
bean id="lineTokenizer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
        <property name="delimiter" value="&" />
        <property name="quoteCharacter"><null/></property>
```

but got another exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customLineMapper' defined in class path resource [migration-job.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lineTokenizer' while setting bean property 'lineTokenizer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lineTokenizer' defined in class path resource [migration-job.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'null' to required type 'char' for property 'quoteCharacter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [null] to required type [char] for property 'quoteCharacter': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CharacterEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [null]
```

Comment: did you try set value to `<null/>`?

Comment: @bellabax I tried right now with null - updated question, still nothing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just answered your linked question a hour ago with my solution, since I ran into this issue today.

Try the solution I posted there. It should work.

Here the link to my answer: [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734632/unterminated-double-quotes-in-spring-batch)

UPDATE:
I paste my answer directly here:

I ran into the same problem. However the proposed solution is not an optimal one. What if in your data there isn't a suitable quote character? Unfortunately we dont' always have control over input data and pre-processing them is not often a good idea. Exploring the DelimitedLineTokenizer source code I decided to adopt this solution that I will share with this answer. It requires to override a class, but with this we totally remove the quote character issue.

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;

    public class CustomDelimitedLineTokenizer extends DelimitedLineTokenizer {

        @Override
        protected boolean isQuoteCharacter(char c) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

This way the DelimitedLineTokenizer can't recognize the quote character. Of course if we need this functionality then this solution is not adoptable, however I think it is better than the proposed one that just sort the issue instead of solving it. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a kludge, but I was able to disable quoting completely by setting the same character both as delimiter and quote character:

```
new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<...>
        .delimited()
        .delimiter("&")
        .quoteCharacter('&')
```