# Spring Batch - FlatFileParseException (record with double quotes)

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I have few records with double quotes in between the field values.

So When i use FlatFileItemReader it throws FlatFileParseException for those records.

The Sample Record is:

```
7^A3989815^A2400284298^ABU^AA" - CLEANING INC.^A$
```

How do we handle this kind of records in Spring Batch Item Readers?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: Can you post execption and item reader code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unterminated Double Quotes in Spring Batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734632/unterminated-double-quotes-in-spring-batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change default quote character to something which you are sure will not appear as suggested [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/107515-facing-issue-with-flatfileitemreader). We had similar problems and changed it to `@` as suggested and it works, but that gives potentially new problem, if `@` appears it will break.

Other solution would be to override `DelimitedLineTokenizer` and to always return `false` from method `isQuoteCharacter` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734632/unterminated-double-quotes-in-spring-batch) which is better solution IMO.

Comment: Thanks @Nenad.. i have used the Custom DelimitedLineTokenizer solution and its working fine. (Since my record contains @ also)