# Spring Batch DelimitedLineTokenizer - parse String with Double Quotes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have records with double quotes which is giving FlatFileParseException. Records are like this `ABC|XYZ|0|1|INVALID "STRING WITH DOUBLE QUOTES USED|E`.

```
@Bean
public LineMapper < Product > lineMapper() {

    DefaultLineMapper < Product > lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper < > ();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokeniser = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|");

    lineTokeniser.setNames("Type", "Owner", "Name",
        "Id", "Discreption", "Category");
    lineTokeniser.setIncludedFields(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper < Product > fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper < > ();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Product.class);
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokeniser);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    return lineMapper;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader < Product > reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader < Product > itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader < > ();
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("c:/files/Product.txt"));
    return itemReader;
}
```

I am using DelimitedLineTokenizer and splitting by "|".
`DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokeniser = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|");`

Any suggestions on how can I handle this.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? and more code?

Comment: Is this the same as https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1822?

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend DelimitedLineTokenizer and return false from isQuoteCharacter to fix this.

**See this working code:**

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;

public class PlainTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer t = new MyDelimitedLineTokenizer("|");
        t.setNames("Type", "Owner", "Name", "Id", "Description", "Category");

        FieldSet fs = t.tokenize("ABC|XYZ|0|1|INVALID \"STRING WITH DOUBLE QUOTES USED|E");
        System.out.println(String.join("\n", fs.getValues()));
        //strip the double quote from Description if needed
    }
}

class MyDelimitedLineTokenizer extends DelimitedLineTokenizer {
    public MyDelimitedLineTokenizer(String d) {
        super(d);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isQuoteCharacter(char c) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

See also:
[Spring Batch - FlatFileParseException (record with double quotes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099559/spring-batch-flatfileparseexception-record-with-double-quotes)