# CSV with Double Quotes -Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading a CSV file using spring batch and few of the records will have double quotes. I can use the regular expression and split the string. But I am not sure where can I implement this logic in the item reader.Not always I will have double quotes value but when I do have it  need to have that as single value

```
String s = "12813,001,,Test,\"Test, Jr\",5440 Winchester Dr, , Concord, NC, 28027-7683,,,,,";
String[] splitted = s.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1);
```

Output

```
[12813, 001, , Test, "Test, Jr", 5440 Winchester Dr,  ,  Concord,  NC,  28027-7683, , , , , ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch DelimitedLineTokenizer - parse String with Double Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64484065/spring-batch-delimitedlinetokenizer-parse-string-with-double-quotes)

Comment: I have implemented the CustomDelimitedLineAggregator extending ExtractorLineAggregator and overriding the do aggregate method

Comment: ok, and were you able to fix your issue with that?

Comment: yes i was able to fix the issue.Thanks for your help